# Array size in Frama-C

Tags: c, frama-c

I'm new in frama-c plugin development.

I would like to ask if there is a way to get array size value and array elements type from Frama-C, either a static or dynamic created array.

For example

```
float *A = (float*)malloc(ni * nk * sizeof(float)); 
int tab[100];
```

I want to perform some pointer aliasing analysis in order to know when and where it is possible to insert restrict keyword.

I don't know if it is possible to modify formals parameters of a function. Take for example this function:

```
void test(int a, int b, int *tmp) {//}
```

If at the end of alias analysis in the body of this function, I'm sure that pointer tmp has not any aliasing situation, then I can insert restrict keyword in tmp declaration by

```
void test(int a, int b, int *__restrict__ tmp) {//}
```

So for that I need to know: pointer base address, if the pointer pointed into an array (constant or dynamic) then get array size and number of array elements.  For now, that's how I formalized the part about getting the array size, the base address and the number of elements:

```
start 
launch value analysis
launch pdg analysis
for kf do 
Get all locals variables (eg: let locals = Kernel_function.get_locals kf;)
    for each local var do 
        if Cil.isPointerType vi.vtype then
        begin 
            find local var declaration (eg: with vi.vdecl);
            print vi.vdecl in output file;
            Know if local var is initialized during the declaration;
            if local var is not initialized during the declaration then
                locate local var initialization or first utilisation;
                print this localisation in output file;
                if this initialization is "an variable assignement" then 
                    match initialization with
                        | ptr = a (where ptr (the local var concerned) and a are pointer type) -> get_base_addr a; get_array_size a; get_num_of_elm a; 
                                                                                                                                                                            print previous get_* results in output file; add ptr to some list
                        | ptr = &val -> match val with
                                                        | Const -> 
                                                        | Lval ->
                                                        | ArrayType -> get_base_addr val; get_array_size val; get_num_of_elm val; 
                                                                                     print previous get_* results in output file; add ptr to some list
                                                        | _ ->
                        | _ ->
                else if this initialization is a dynamic allocation (eg: with malloc, ...) then 
                    get_base_addr ptr; get_array_size ptr; get_num_of_elm ptr; 
                    print previous get_* results in output file; add ptr to some list
            else if local var is initialized during the declaration then
            (*----*)
        end 
        else if Cil.isArrayType vi.vtype then
            get_base_addr ptr; get_array_size ptr; get_num_of_elm ptr; 
            print previous get_* results in output file; add ptr to some list
        else 
            (*local var is not a pointer and not an array*)
    end of for 
    Get list of all called functions;
    Know if previous pointers or arrays analysed are passed as parameters to some functions in this list and print the name of these functions;
    (*-----------*) 
end of for ; end
```

I looked at the file Cil_types.mli and db.mli (in order to use some Db.Value.* functions) and found some types like (TPtr and TArray ) and many useful functions (mk*) but for the moment but for now I have not really understood how to use them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Syntactic information is available in Frama-C AST, which is documented in `src/kernel_services/ast_data/cil_types.mli`. For the size of dynamically allocated object, you need some kind of analysis, and the answer is completely dependent on the context (what kind of code you want to analyse, how broad is the context of the analysis, how precise should the result be, ...). There's not enough information now to provide a definitive answer.